# Asp.Net validators and read only textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a readonly textbox that has a required validator attached to it. This textbox can only be filled using other controls.

The problem is that read only textboxes do not store their value and restore it on postback, so this is causing the validator to flare up each time there is a post back. I know there are ways to force it to store the value, but I actually don't want it to store it.

Is there anyway past this?

Edit: This is the control causing the problems:

```
            <li class="fakeUploadLi">
                <asp:Label CssClass="lbl" ID="lb" runat="server" Text="Image:"></asp:Label>
                <div class="fakeupload">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFakeupload" Enabled="false" />
                </div>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fuImage" runat="server" CssClass="fileUpload" onchange="this.form.ctl00$cphAdmin$tbFakeupload.value = this.value;" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="newImage" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbFakeupload"
                    ErrorMessage="Please select an image first.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </li>
```

It is an overlay over the original FileUpload html control. Note that if I turn off readonly (or Enabled, tried both) the problem goes away.

Comment: Why don't you try to store the value of `tbFakeupload` in `hidden field` and restore it after `PostBack` that way it will never lose it's value and the validator will not fire

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33649/ViewState-and-Readonly-Property-of-Textbox

Comment: Did you read my question? I said I don't want to store the value. I already know about this trick, I want it to not flare up on each post back.

Comment: then maybe add some more information on what you are doing and in what context your textfield is located, i have replicated your question myself with a validator etc and it doesnt fire up for me.

Comment: My problem goes away as soon as I turn off readonly. It's strange. I added the html for the control in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `readonly` property to `Enabled = "false"`